# %SourceFileName% macro does not work with Blob Storage adapter bizTalk2020

Tags: biztalk, blobstore, biztalk-2020

I have a flow where receive location is blob storage and I use Azure Blob Storage adapter. Then I don't have any orchestrations, mapping and so on, just a send port as file share adapter.
In the file name I use `%SourceFileName%` macro.

But after all destination file name is exact "%SourceFileName%" instead of real source file name.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the context properties of the message from the BizTalk Admin console.  Is there a ReceivedFilename property?  If there isn't then there isn't a lot you can do.  Have you checked the Promote metadata properties?

Comment: here it calls receivedBlobName and it's not promoted. So i think i need to promote it in receive pipeline and create an orchestration which will assign this promoted value to destination file name

Comment: So there is a property there that has the filename?   If you want to keep it messaging only, you could use something like the BRE Pipeline Framework https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework to promote the property, without having an Orchestration.